# verb + to a whole new level

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

I'm wondering, which verb is the most common one and the best one with the phrase "to a whole new level"?

- lead
- bring
- take
- raise

Example:

- This discovery will *(lead,bring,take,raise)* evolution to a whole new level.

Comment: Have you tried using corpora? Considering your rep, I believe you know what they are.

Comment: @Yes.. but Google N-gram gives no results and you can'[t put more than 5 words there, even with the * sign the search yields only one result for "lead to * new level,raise to * new level,bring to * new level,take to * new level"

Comment: Have you heard of COCA/BNC? Try there.

Comment: I'm not too sure about your example context. Evolution just ***happens***, regardless of what we find out about the details of ***how*** it works, so I don't see how a "discovery" can take evolution to a "new level". Ozone layer depletion could perhaps make evolution proceed *faster* (more random variation caused by radiation damage), but that's a change of circumstance, not a discovery. As for which verb to use in your context, it's really a personal stylistic choice, but my guess is ***raise*** is the more common choice for most people in most contexts.

Comment: @SovereignSun I don't know much about corpora. But I think if you use COCA, you can try `[*n] to a whole new level`

Comment: @userr2684291 Can't understand how to search there, it always gives 0 results.

Comment: @SovereignSun https://web.archive.org/web/20160316082907/http://corpus.byu.edu:80/coca/help/syntax_e.asp

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22takes%20things%20to%20a%20whole%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en  Ironic that people who are excited about new levels would use such a tired phrase, no?  :)

Comment: @SovereignSun - Should you be translating this from Russian into English, I'd wonder how the source sentence might read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just looking for a verb of some kind - the one you use depends on the context.

Any of the words you suggest could work along with a bunch that you haven't listed, like kick, shove, move, throw, etc.

The phrase, "to a whole new level," assumes that a thing has been at one point, but something is changing and causing it to move to a new point, or new level.

For example: I was on a special diet, but my weight hadn't changed for a long time until I started exercising.  Exercising pushed my weight loss to a whole new level.

Or

Exercising moved my weight loss to a whole new level.

Either one sounds fine.  It all depends on what kind of emphasis you want to give.

Comment: Well, I know what it means and that I can use other words. I've selected these four as the ones I see most and want to know which one is the most common one and the best in most cases.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say above... you can't just pick the best or most common and say, "That's the one I'm going to use," because everything depends on context.  Are you speaking emphatically, or sarcastically, or whatever?  English has lots of verbs... you don't have to pick just one.

Comment: I'm aware that it all depends on context, however, I want a trendy word, not just any word. I'm speaking proffesionally. Imagine a science paper saying that.

Comment: The discover isn't going to do anything to evolution... It might do something to the study of evolution... I would probably use the word, "lead."  The discovery will lead the study of evolution to a whole new level.  Or... The discovery will raise our understanding of evolution to a whole new level.  Again... context.

Answer (score 0):

**Evolve**

> The discovery will evolve evolution to a whole new level.